# Drools - Using a global variable in condition and updating it in consequence

Tags: drools

I have following question. Hope someone can answer .

In my drools project I'm executing some selection rules and selected objects are added to global list. Then there are another  rules which use objects in this global list. I expect Drools to fire those global list dependent rules every time list changes ( when another rule add object to list ). But seems like this not happening on Drools. Does drools track changes done to global variable and resolve rules which depends on them ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4569):

> Globals are not inserted into the Working Memory, and therefore a global should never be used to establish conditions in rules except when it has a constant immutable value.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the help. :). I removed fact dependencies on condition clause. Instead used a flag in the class. Now it's working !